# Java - Захват аудио выхода

Tags: java, аудио

Требуется записать аудио со стандартного аудио выхода(т.е. звук, который пользователь слышит, например, во время просмотра видео). Основная проблема заключается в том, что SourceDataLine не имеет метода read.
Мой код:

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, false);
DataLine.Info   info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = null;
try
{
    sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    // Как считать аудио с sourceDataLine?

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Этот код помог:

```
Mixer.Info[] mixersInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

Mixer.Info selectedMixerInfo = mixersInfo[0];
TargetDataLine recordLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(
    aAudioFormat, selectedMixerInfo
);
```

Comment: Зачем вы ответ @Andrew опубликовали еще раз ?

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю,что это возможно только в случае, если у тебя есть виртуальный аудиодевайс (родной драйвер звуковухи с "What U Hear" фичей, [Virtual Audio Cable](http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm), Virtual Audio Streaming или подобным).

А код будет приблизительно следующим:

```
Mixer.Info[] mixersInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

//выбрать виртуальный аудиодевайс по имени, версии или вендору
Mixer.Info selectedMixerInfo = mixersInfo[0];
TargetDataLine recordLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(aAudioFormat, selectedMixerInfo);
```

Оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099876/java-capture-soundoutput
Дополнительно можешь погуглить по "java Capture audio output"